# Automatically download S3 images, ZIP them and re-upload back to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3

My question is regarding the AWS platform and I have a fairly complicated issue I am trying to solve.

I have images that are stored in an AWS S3 bucket. These images need to be zipped and re-uploaded to the S3 bucket that they are downloaded from. I have created a docker image that utilizes linux ZIP and UNZIP commands in conjunction with the AWS CLI to perform this task. I can run this docker image manually and it performs the job perfectly.

**The problem:** I am struggling to figure out the AWS platform so that I may automate this docker image. My ideal scenario is the docker image spins up automatically when required, performs the task and then shuts itself back off. I know something similar to this is possible using AWS ECS. However, I am woefully over my head here. I'd love to open a dialogue with someone who knows how to wrangle AWS to complete this task.

PS. I am mainly looking for guidance on how to do this, I have the docker Image already.

Comment: Do the zip files each contain one image? Or are you zipping multiple images into a single zip file? Also, this site really isn't for "dialoging" so much as asking specific questions about a specific issue you are facing.

Comment: Also, when your docker image runs, how does it determine which image(s) in S3 need to be zipped? Does the docker container need to run when specific files appear in S3, or simply on a set schedule?

Answer (score 1):

Use Lambda to start an AWS fargate task using your image

This blog goes into detail in implention such a solution
https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-application-for-long-running-process-fargate-lambda/